# Mongodb-How to pass collection field as a variable to get data from another collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to get study materials related to a subject from 'study material' collection when subject name from 'subject' collection is passed.

```
router.get('/materials',(req,res) =>{
    
    Materials.find({"subjectName":"Physics"}).exec((err,materials) =>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:err
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success:true,
            existingMaterials:materials
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I have got so far.How to pass subject name as a variable?

I did the react part this way. Is this correct?

```
export default class ViewSubjectMaterial extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state={
          materials:[]
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount(){
        this.retrieveMaterials();
      }
      
      retrieveMaterials(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:8000/materials?subjectName=Physics").then(res =>{
          if(res.data.success){
            this.setState({
              materials:res.data.existingMaterials
            });
      
            console.log(this.state.materials)
          }
        })
      }}
```

Comment: please provide your sample data of Materials

Comment: subjectName=Physics,curriculum=Intro to matter,topic=What is matter?,notes=Matter notes 1. Something similar to this

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?

```
router.get('/materials',(req,res) =>{
const subjectName = req.query.subjectName;


Materials.find({"subjectName":subjectName}).exec((err,materials) =>{
    if(err){
        return res.status(400).json({
            error:err
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        existingMaterials:materials
    });
});
});
```

Then, you will have to send this in the request query. for example:

`GET http://localhost:8000/materials?subjectName=Physics`

Comment: `GET http://localhost:8000/materials?subjectName=Physics` Please tell me how to code this in react .

Comment: You should use a library for http requests, lets say `node-fetch` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch then you execute a GET request with the library

Answer (score 0):

change get to post method

```
router.post('/materials',(req,res) =>{

/// {subjectName:"Physics",curriculum:"Intro"} example of req.body
Materials.find(req.body).exec((err,materials) =>{
    if(err){
        return res.status(400).json({
            error:err
        });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        existingMaterials:materials
    });
});
});
```

add these lines in index js where express defined

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```